# reactjs nodejs getting error cannot get and error status 404

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, jwt

Hello im making auth system. i can create account and data pass perfrectly and its look fine but when i go to login page i cannot login with created user in to data base user is exsiting and also displayed on dashboard when i click login i get error
xhr.js:220 POST http://localhost:5000/login 404 (Not Found)
im understand that problem is syntax but cannot get it .

login.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
 
const Login = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [msg, setMsg] = useState('');
    const navigate = useNavigate();
 
    const Auth = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/login', {
                email: email,
                password: password
            }); 
            navigate("/dashboard");
        } catch (error) {
            if (error.response) {
                setMsg(error.response.data.msg);
            }
        }
    }
 
    return (
        <section className="hero has-background-grey-light is-fullheight is-fullwidth">
            <div className="hero-body">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="columns is-centered">
                        <div className="column is-4-desktop">
                            <form onSubmit={Auth} className="box">
                                <p className="has-text-centered">{msg}</p>
                                <div className="field mt-5">
                                    <label className="label">Email or Username</label>
                                    <div className="controls">
                                        <input type="text" className="input" placeholder="Username" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="field mt-5">
                                    <label className="label">Password</label>
                                    <div className="controls">
                                        <input type="password" className="input" placeholder="******" value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="field mt-5">
                                    <button className="button is-success is-fullwidth">Login</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    )
}
 
export default Login
```

Comment: Can you post the code responsible for initializing the `/login` end-point on the back-end?

Answer (score 0):

`404` means that API is not found, so `http://localhost:5000/login`, there is no route in your server for '/login' which redirects you to the login method.

May you mean `http://localhost:5000/api/login`?

For more resources:

https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/websites/website-creation/what-does-the-404-not-found-error-mean/

Comment: now its start working and accounts is working to i can login with created account but now a problem is if i  type bad email or password i get message that its not found but if i do not type anything in labels i get login in :D